# Disadvantage to Large Initialization List?

Tags: c++, initialization-list

At my employer, it is policy that we use initialization lists in the constructor because it is more efficient.

However, I am developing a class that has 45 data members requiring initialization. Per the policy, this would have to be done in an initialization list in the constructor.

Other than readability, what would be the disadvantage to a large initialization list?

Comment: Other than readability?  I can't think of anything, besides the potential for error.

Comment: Hint: If you have 45 member attributes you might not be dividing the responsibilities appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can format a member initializer list over multiple physical source lines so there doesn't have to be a readability issue.

The larger issue is obviously the fact that you have classes with 45 data members. Nothing is going to make working with such classes particularly easy.

---

```
AClass::AClass( type1 val1
              , type2 val2
              // ...
              , type45 val45 )
: mem1( val1 )
, mem2( val2 )
// ...
, mem45( val45 )
{
}
```

I argue is no less readable than:

```
AClass::AClass( type1 val1
              , type2 val2
              // ...
              , type45 val45 )
{
    mem1 = val1;
    mem2 = val2;
     // ...
    mem45 = val45;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it might be worth taking a step back to understand why your class has 45 data members.  This is usually a sign that your class is doing too many things, and has too many separate responsibilities that is going to make this class very hard to maintain over time.

It sounds like you may need to break your class into separate functional pieces and have the 'controller' class delegate to subclasses.  This is going to decrease the complexity of your code dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like well known anti-pattern **God object**. Wiki citation:

[In object-oriented programming, a God object is an object that knows too much or does too much.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Please find a way to reconsider your design to group members of the god object into smaller structures and objects with their own initialization procedures.

So an answer to the question "what would be the disadvantage to a large initialization list? (comparing to a small one)" could be "**It is large, so possibly it is a bad style.**"

An answer to the question "what would be the disadvantage to a large initialization list? (comparing to a large constructor body)" could be "**none**", because initialization better be done in the list, not in the body, but readability and a cost of maintenance the same (as for me).

Comment: Which part of this answers the question about disadvantages of large initialization lists?

Comment: The part that says, "if you have large initialization lists, then *that* is a problem."

Answer (score -1):

Some optimizations will fail, I suspect that inlining of such a constructor will not work.

Either way: 45 Data members sound a lot. Can you group them so aggregated Objects?

Comment: why would they fail with an initializer list and not without an initializer list (where you would copy those initializations to the body)?